# Amazon web service console- access denied for manifest file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am new to Amazon web CloudFront console and S3 buckets. I am trying to get on-demand streaming work. When tried to view my uploaded video- ism file in the s3 bucket, I get the following XML response when entered following URL in a web browser:

http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/videos/video_1/BigBuckBunny.ism/Manifest

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>C1EC48985EE12047</RequestId>
<HostId>
L7JtCmEHm9W3HUeZEV08GyoFBxiC4krHvoiQyPZrYxeOaIP8yhMJKP60+eIo5qTZcsDasW48Ck8=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

I am able to download this same ism file, using an url; http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/videos/video_1/BigBuckBunny.ism. Then why only an issue with the manifest file which I will be accessing from my application?

From the following documentation given on Amazon, I have followed all 4 steps and I am now stuck at Step- 5.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/on-demand-streaming-smooth.html

What could I be missing?  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon S3 does not know how to handle ism files, that's why /manifest doesn't work.  What you need to do is configure your distribution with smooth streaming enabled, like the link you provided, and replace the s3 URL with cloudfront.

http://d124.cloudfront.net/videos/video_1/BigBuckBunny.ism/Manifest